# Whonix custom workstation: Is it possible to automaticly detect whonix gateway?

Tags: virtualbox, ip, ethernet, gateway, whonix

I use Whonix downloaded gateway and custom OS as Whonix workstation (in VirtualBox).
To connect the workstation to the gateway I need to manually set Address, Mask and Gateway to `10.152.152.10`, `255.255.192.0`, `10.152.152.10`. But I can do it only after OS install. Is it possible to make Whonix gateway ethernet automatically detected by the workstation OS? I want a gateway to be determined automatically during the installation of the OS, as if it is a simple internet, like NAT.
Hope for your help!

Answer (score 0):

At time of writing: No.

That would require running a DHCP server "somewhere". Details:

https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Dev/DHCP